# SQL INNER JOIN entity

Tags: sql

I want to execute this query :

```
-- The most expensive item sold ever
SELECT 
    c.itemID, c.itemName
FROM 
    item AS c
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         b.itemID as 'itemid', MAX(b.item_initialPrice) AS 'MaxPrice' 
     FROM 
         buyeritem AS a
     INNER JOIN 
         item AS b ON a.item_ID = b.itemID) AS d ON c.itemID = d.itemid 
GROUP BY
    c.itemID, c.itemName;
```

My `item` table looks like this:

```
create table item
(
    itemID int IDENTITY(1000, 1) NOT NULL,
    itemName varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Item_desc varchar(255),
    Item_initialPrice MONEY,
    ItemQty int,
    ownerID int NOT NULL,
    condition varchar(20) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (itemID),

    FOREIGN KEY (ownerID) REFERENCES seller (sellerID) 
);
```

The problem is that column `item.itemID` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause. I tried to add a group by clause at the end

```
group by c.itemID, c.itemName
```

but I still get the same error? I don't really know where the problem comes from.

I also have this query

```
-- The most active seller(the one who has offered the most number of items)
SELECT 
    a.ownerID, b.sellerName 
FROM 
    item AS a
INNER JOIN 
    seller AS b ON a.ownerID = b.sellerID
GROUP BY 
    a.ownerID, b.sellerName 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(a.itemID) DESC;
```

I want to add `itemQty` along with the `ownerID` and `sellerName` from `item` table stated above, what would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Get the first query working directly in your database and then worry about the JDBC code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write distinct instead of Group By as Group By will not work with out an aggregated function like sum,max etc. in select statement which is missing in your query.An example of this is second query which I have written

```
SELECT distinct c.itemID, c.itemName
FROM item AS c
JOIN (
SELECT b.itemID as itemid, MAX(b.item_initialPrice) AS MaxPrice FROM buyeritem AS a
INNER JOIN item AS b ON a.item_ID = b.itemID 
GROUP BY b.itemID) as d
ON c.itemID = d.itemid ;
```

For second query

```
Select a.* from
(
SELECT a.ownerID, b.sellerName, count(distinct a.ITEM_ID) as item_qty
FROM item AS a
INNER JOIN seller AS b ON a.ownerID = b.sellerID
GROUP BY a.ownerID,b.sellerName 
) a
order by item_qty DESC
```

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it. Now it should work in most of the DBMS

Comment: tnx for your feedback, I also checked distinct before(forgot to mention that on my question) but it throws the same error though? btw there is an aggregated function MAX() in the query??

Comment: @red did you try the query which i have given

Comment: EDITED it to include group by. forgot to include that initially in the query

Comment: @you are welcome. Please Accept the answer. To know how to do this, visit this link stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers